# How to call non-static method of another class

Tags: java, android

I want to understand how to call a non-static method of one class in another class.

I have seen something like the following:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.doSomething();
```

when the method Class1 is called in another class.

```
public class AddA extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_a);
        final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) this.findViewById(R.id.DatePicker);
        final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) this.findViewById(R.id.TimePicker);

 Button clear = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subject.setText("");
                message.setText("");
                //DatePicker.setCurrentDateOnView();
                //TimePicker.setCurrentTimeOnView();
                DateTimePicker datePicker = new DateTimePicker();
                datePicker.setCurrentDateOnView(); //null here
            }

        });
//...More code
}
```

---

```
public class DateTimePicker extends AddA {
      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_alerts);

            setCurrentDateOnView();
            setCurrentTimeOnView();
        }

        // display current date
        public void setCurrentDateOnView() { //null here


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // set current date into datepicker
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

        }
    ///..More code}
```

I would greatly appreciate a detailed explanation. Yes, I have researched this notion, but I just cannot grasp it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, _which_ `DatePicker` do you want to set the current date of?  _Which_ `TimePicker`?

Comment: Okay, so according to this code, you are creating a *brand-new* DateTimePicker, setting the current date, then immediately trashing it when you exit the `onClick`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @cricket_007 Say a user selects a date and time, and then selects a clear button that clears the form (including that date and time). When the user selects that clear button, I want to reset the date and time to the current date and time.

Comment: use your `final DatePicker`. Do not create a new one.

Comment: Looking at the current code, just remove the line `DateTimePicker datePicker = new DateTimePicker();`. I assume `final DatePicker datePicker` is visible.

Comment: @user1803551 I cannot remove that line because the method setCurrentDateOnView() is in another class called DateTimePicker.

Comment: You are calling `setCurrentDateOnView()` on a class of type `DatePicker`. Since you have an instance of that class initialized already, then use that instance to call the method. You are not showing us in which class each piece of code is so we can only guess.

Comment: @user1803551 - OP is calling on class of type `DateTimePicker` with the variable name of `datePicker`. Very confusing!

Comment: Where are the final variables defined? In which class / context?

Comment: @user1803551 In the class that is not the DateTimePicker class so in the class where the clear button is.

Comment: @cricket_007 His question changes every few seconds. I see his `DateTimePicker` only inside `onClick`, but the `final` variables are either `DatePicker` or `TimePicker`. Which of his classes should actually invoke `setCurrentDateOnView`?

Comment: For each code snippet, write which class it is in. Otherwise we have no idea what is visible to whom.

Comment: @user1803551 I have two classes: DateTimePicker and the class that has the button. In the class that has the button, I am trying to call the DateTimePicker's method of setCurrentDateOnView. So the final variables are NOT in the DateTimePicker, but in the class with the button.

Comment: Okay, your problem is that `DateTimePicker` is an Activity, not a Picker in any fashion since you `extend AddA`, which is itself an Activity. Why can you not move `setCurrentDateOnView` to `AddA`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Looking for a way to just call the DateTimePicker method in AddA to prevent excess code in AddA.

Comment: Suddenly everything is much clearer. is `setCurrentDateOnView` defined for `DatePicker` and `Timepicker`? The commented code suggests that you want to do this.

Comment: setCurrentDateonView is defined for DatePicker in the class DateTimePicker

Comment: You can't. `DateTimePicker` is an entirely separate activity with no access to the date or time pickers from `AddA` since you overwrote the layout content view and are not using class inheritance appropriately. You need to operate on the views within the Activity in which they are defined.

Comment: I'm completely lost now with what you are trying to achieve in they way this is written. Detective cricket, good luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98662/discussion-on-question-by-johnwilliams-how-to-call-non-static-method-of-another).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need class inheritance at all to acheive the problem in your question.

I was able to throw this working example together that resets both pickers to the current date.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button resetButton;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
                timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"/>
    <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Or if you want methods to set the date and time, you can do this

```
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                setDate(c);
                setTime(c);
            }
        });


} // end onCreate

private void setDate(Calendar c) {
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);
}

private void setTime(Calendar c) {
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
}
```